# eGPU for macbook pro 2019

Tags: rendering

I hope I am in the right place.

I have a 2019 macbook pro, 13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports, 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5, 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 645 1536 MB

I have been researching online the next step of optimizing my performance in Blender, but everything I'm finding is conflicting and outdated.

Do I need an eGPU? What is the best option for a macbook with my specs?